# Can someone verify that the damage could have been caused by the accident?

Tags: ford

[image]

I was rear ended a month ago at about 60 MPH. The impact had broken the seal between the axle and the wheel hub. Insurance is trying to get out of it saying that it had been leaking long before the accident but I know for a fact that it hadn't. They are saying that the accident couldn't have caused the damage to the axle. I want a second opinion. Can someone verify that the damage could have been caused by the accident?

Comment: Share pictures from the day. We can evaluate.

Comment: If your argument is true, then any bump in the road hit by a wheel and tire at more than 60mph will damage a hub seal and cause them to leak. As this does not happen, then IMHO, it was not damaged by the accident. If the wheel had impacted a kerb and bent the shaft then that would be different.

Comment: @SolarMike - I'd tend to agree with the assessment the accident wouldn't cause it to leak, though in your scenario a wheel moves vertically, but not horizontally (with any kind of give). A 60mph hit from either of the X or Y axis is an impact the suspension does not normally take. To the OP: If it has been leaking, the oil which is there would appear old with new oil over the top of it (grime with oil over it). If it were from the accident, the grime wouldn't be there (unless you keep the bottom of your vehicle spotless).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 When a wheel hits a bump, the impact cause a force in both the x and y directions -  the x force being felt as a deceleration while the y force is absorbed by the spring/shock unit. You may find this interesting (not a complete analysis though): https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/23524/10902

Comment: This picture was the day after the accident

Comment: @SolarMike - Not like it does during an accident. Think about it. The suspension is made to go up and down, not to the side. If this weren't so, we'd never get it to align.

Comment: I know for a fact that it wasn't leaking before the accident. It can not be coincidental that it starts leaking the day after the accident.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the OP said rear ended so what side impact?

Comment: The guy hit me in the passenger rear pushing the truck to the right

Comment: How far has it been driven after the accident?

Comment: @SolarMike A rolling wheel hitting an incline at 60 MPH is nothing like a vehicle collision at 60 MPH. Suspensions are definitely not designed to handle that kind of impact.

Comment: So you say the impact was 60mph? So you were stationary and the other car 60mph? Or were you doung 40mph and the other car 60mph so impact speed actually 20mph?

Comment: I was at a stop. The impact itself was a 60 mph impact

Comment: My truck gets parked in the same spot in my driveway and there are no oil stains anywhere in that spot. If you look at the picture, the picture itself indicates a fresh leak because if it was old it would be all over the place

Comment: It was only driven about 20 miles after the accident

Comment: Wow - I am impressed you could drive away. I have been in a stationary vehicle hit at 50mph, and there was no way it could even be considered a vehicle after that.

Answer (score 0):

What you really need to do is find a mechanic who can inspect the actual vehicle and provide an expert opinion as to whether it was caused by the accident or not. The opinions of a bunch of people from the internet are not going to hold much weight with the insurance company, especially based solely on looking at a picture.

It seems reasonable to me that the leak could be accident-related, but it's also possible that there was already a leak and the impact just worsened, it, making it more obvious.

You're going to have to get it repaired either way, so I'd suggest having the work done, at which point the parts can be inspected by a mechanic, more pictures taken, and you may have a better idea of when the problem started, and can decide whether it's worth pursuing a claim with the insurance company.

I don't see any way to conclusively prove that it wasn't leaking before, so it's going to come down to an opinion from someone the insurance company considers an expert.

Comment: Most insurance companies can source independant assessors...

Answer (score 0):

I can verify that the damage could have been caused by the accident.  I can't say that it definitely was though.

I'd suggest disassembling the hub, replacing the seal and topping up any lost fluids.

As regards cause and blame, let your solicitors battle it out in court if you feel you want to pursue it.  I'd suggest the first thing you want to do, before doing the repair, is to instruct an independent expert to produce an engineers report.  I'd also suggest retaining the broken parts removed when you do the repair.

The focus of this page is the service and repair of machines.  I'd suggest seeking professional legal advice if you intend to chase the insurers.  There isn't a court in the land that will accept the opinion of users of an internet group looking at some digital pictures over the word of an insurance appointed mechanical specialist.